# Angular: Events and "subscribe is not a function" error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have just started diving into some basic Angular 4 and am stuck listening to an emitted event. Here's a pretty minimal example that reproduces the problem (at least on my end):

`DateSenderComponent` is "broadcasting" the current date which is then to be processed by its parent `AppComponent` (see below):

```
import { Component, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-sender',
  template: '<button (click)="sendDate()">Send</button>'
})

export class DateSenderComponent {
  @Output() dateSent = new EventEmitter();

  sendDate(){
    var dt = new Date();
    console.log(dt);
    this.dateSent.emit(dt.toString());
  }
}
```

`AppComponent` is supposed to listen to the broadcasted date event:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<app-date-sender (dateSent)="dateReceived($event)"></app-date-sender>'
})

export class AppComponent {
  dateReceived(value){
    console.log('Result: ', value);
  }
}
```

From various beginners tutorials I figured this is the way to listen to events. However, instead of printing out the received date value, when loading the page I get the following error:

> AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: instance[output.propName].subscribe is not a function
>
> at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10727)
>
> at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12086)
>
> at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12530)
>
> at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12439)
>
> at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12113)
>
> at createRootView (core.es5.js:11991)
>
> at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13206)
>
> at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12666)
>
> at ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9912)
>
> at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3448)

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any information about what this actually means and I also couldn't figure it out on my own.

One thing that seems to be a hint: When I change the `AppComponent` template to listen to some event that doesn't get emitted anywhere (for example `<app-date-sender (someStringSent)="dateReceived($event)"></app-date-sender>`) then the error disappears. So there seems to be a connection between the actual output event and the template listening to it and it seems to be the cause of the problem.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: import { EventEmitter } from "events"; this should be import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

Comment: @RahulSingh Thanks a lot, you're absolutely right. Some sloppiness on my end...

Answer (score 152, accepted):

`EventEmitter` should come from `'@angular/core'`

I see in your code it comes from `'events'`.

Are you sure it is the correct object that you are using?

Comment: You're right, thanks a lot. In my defense (or rather a desperate try to blame someone else): This was the first suggestion by Visual Studio Code when I hit `Ctrl+.` after typing `new EventEmitter()`. And I didn't even look at the other three :)

Comment: Same issue here. Bad autocomplete in VSCode.

Comment: This is a bug with TypeScript [Issue #19888](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19888) will be fixed soon!

Comment: just ran into this same problem.. not fix yet it seems

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio Code suggested EventEmitter from events. 
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 28):

The problem is here:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";
```

You have to import `EventEmitter` from`@angular/core` like this:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
```